# How to highlight text with padding in html with liquid variable

Tags: html, jekyll, highlight

I'm working with jelkyll and I want to highlight the heading with a predefined liquid variable in the front matter of the specific post.

So in my post.md file I have this:

```
---
title: hello
color: aaa
---
```

Next I have a post.html file with the following code:

```
<h1 class="page-title">{{page.title}}</h1>
```

Highlighting it a standard yellow does work:

```
  <h1 class="page-title" style="background-color:yellow">{{page.title}}</h1>
```

But when i change yellow with `#{{post.color}}` it doesn't work. I also can't seem to move the color around. I want to achieve something like [here](http://www.andersnoren.se/teman/rams-wordpress-theme/) is done with the word "rams".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach your color with `{{ page.color }}`.